# How to get an image size earlier to determine a views size?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

Here is a view with a `UIImageView` in it. I will set different images to it determined by different situation. So what i do is to get the size of image to resize the view. Do we have a better way to determine the size of the `UIImageView` and not to resize its size?

I face this problem when i have a `UITableViewCell` in the middle of a `UITableView`. I show my tableview first without the image. Then after i got the image, i reload the cell to resize the image view. It seems it is not so good in visual effect.

Comment: you can do 1 thing. While downloading the images, after downloading the image you check the ratio of the image and resize it so that you can fit it perfectly with the tableview cell's imageView (as you know its height and width from beforehand), and then reload the tableview, using the resized image.

Comment: One of the nastiest problems that needs to be solved server side. Asynchronous image loading in table view cells is a chicken and egg scenario. To render a cell, you need to tell it the width and height, but to get width and height of image, you need to wait for image to finish downloading. A good solution, If possible, is to ask your backend programmer to include the image width and height information in the JSON response. That way, your JSON already provide you the dimension of the image needed, before image finish downloading, to determine table cell dimensions.